# Setting multiple alarms

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

So far I have this method which sets up a repeating alarm. This one sets an alarm up at 11:15am at 15 minute intervals. I am wondering if I wanted to set another repeating alarm for 12:00am alongside this alarm, do I need to do anything different?

Also, is it possible to have several kinds of views to show when an alarm goes off? If I wanted one view to pop up at 11:15am and a different view to pop up at 12:36pm, can I set that up? If so, how?

```
private void setCollectionAlarms() {

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    interval = 900000;

    try {
        //If the date is set to HHmm, then add current date time
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String time = "11:15";

        long timeOfFirstCollectionInMillis = format.parse(time).getTime();
        System.out.println("Time in Milis: " + timeOfFirstCollectionInMillis);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.setTime(new Date());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date timedate = format.parse(time);
        cal.setTime(timedate); // thinks 1970
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, now.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        //If the time from the db is before now (That is no date set but time set), then set it for tomorrow
        if (cal.before(now)) {
            // increase
            Date tomorrow = cal.getTime();
            cal.setTime(tomorrow);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            tomorrow = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println("TimeDate for Tomorrow: " + tomorrow);

            //convert date to milis
            long timeInMilis = (tomorrow.getTime());

            //Set Alarm to Repeat
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilis, interval, pendingIntent);


            //else, set the alarm for today
        } else {
            timedate = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println("TimeDate: " + timedate);

            //convert date to milis
            long timeInMilis = (timedate.getTime());

            //Set Alarm to Repeat
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilis, interval, pendingIntent);


        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a quick note to bring to your attention the behaviour of setRepeating changed in KitKat - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html it's no longer exact (in case that matters)

Comment: oh thanks! I do need an exact repeating alarm. Is this still possible?

Comment: Yes, `setExact()` will still work correctly. It's a bit of a pain now, if you want it to be accurate, you need to set an new alarm when you handle the event (in your `BroadcastReceiver`) from setExact, effectively making a chain of alarms, the last one setting the time for the next one.

Comment: So should I set two alarms in a row? SetExact() and then use SetRepeating(SetExact())? Can I nest it like that?

Comment: setExact will set a single alarm. When the alarm goes off, you can handle it in your BroadcastReceiver (it looks like yours is called AlarmReceiver?). When you handle the alarm that's just gone off, you can set another using setExact again.

Comment: Sounds a little confusing... hm this is mostly what I have in my AlarmReceiver class: Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service); I have a service that displays a notification when alarm goes off.

Comment: @BenPearson, can you provide me with an example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm actually doing something quite similar in one of my apps. I was planning to blog about how it worked on Sunday, I can post a link to it (as an answer) once I've written the post.

Comment: It will be too late for me then because I get off this project today but I would still be interested in learning from you. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I've just finished writing a blog post on this topic. You'll want to handle all of the logic for what you want to do when the alarm is triggered and the code inside your class that extends BroadcastReceiver runs.

[Android bytes: Alarms](http://rdyonline.net/android-bytes-alarms/)

Hopefully that's clear enough, but if you have any more questions, I can update the answer.

Comment: Hi Ben, I have one more question, if wanted to save the alarm values in my database and update the value to the new alarm time, how can I do that?  How do I know when an alarm is triggered? I would like to save the alarm trigger and it's value but how do I know when the alarm will go off?

Comment: Hopefully that was clear from the blog post? When the alarm is triggered, you'll step in to the BroadcastReceiver. If you want to update an alarm, you can remove it and then add it. If it helped at all, an upvote would be appreciated.